# can not find "rxtools" after install ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Tags: ubuntu, ros

#### personal environment

- VMWare 14.X
- ubuntu 16.04
- ROS package: ros-kinetic-desktop-full

#### My doubt

Why my full package didn't contain Rxtools? And where can I download it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, It seems that it was not contained in `kinetic` but `etectric`,`fuerte` and `groovy`?

referrd : http://wiki.ros.org/rxtools

And we can use `rqt_console` to do the same things as `rxtools` in fuerte.